# VSTS Release Agent on Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, docker-swarm-mode

I would like to use a VSTS release agent on a Raspberry Pi, but I don't see anything in the [VSTS Agent GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent) that would indicate it is possible.  My vision is a VSTS build agent on a Raspberry pi to build, package, and push a docker image to DockerHub, and then a release agent to deploy the docker images into a Raspberry Pi docker swarm cluster.  Does anybody have experience doing something like this?  I'm not married to using VSTS if there is a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Try it. If you encounter a specific issue, ask a question here.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMann for giving me a gentle push.  I was hoping this question would save me from stumbling around, but I"ll give it a shot.  I've now download the repo to a Raspberry Pi and am working through trying to get it to build.  If it actually works, I'll report back here for anyone else who is interested.

Comment: Can you run docker image on Raspberry Pi? There is the image for VSTS agent: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker. On the other hand, this article may benefit you: [A Raspberry Pi3 VSTS Build Light–Part 1, the hardware](http://myalmblog.com/2016/05/a-raspberry-pi3-vsts-build-light-part-1-the-hardware/)